# Vagrant/Virtualbox Nginx Provisioning

Tags: laravel-4, vagrant, virtualbox, provisioning

I'm running Laravel/Homestead as my Vagrant box and have heard that Nginx has some weird caching issues. The way to solve the problem is to set "sendfille off" in the nginx config file.

How can I provision my Laravel/Homestead Vagrant box so that I don't have to ssh into the box and modify the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your host's homestead folder you can find `homestead/scripts/serve.sh`. There sendfile is already set to off as default for your app. I think this will set nginx sendfile option to off.

If you still want to edit the `nginx.conf` permanently, write a line of code into `serve.sh` to change the config file.

#### More info on serve.sh

The `serve.sh` script will run on `--provision` for any site configured in the `Homestead.yaml`.

It creates each site in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and symlinks it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Nginx and php5-fpm get restarted after that.

In `nginx.conf` we can see at the end of the `http{...}`-block has:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

This includes all sites in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` where the `server{...}`-blocks are defined. For more information about nginx config look at the [Nginx Admin Guide](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide reference on the serve.sh? Does this file directly impact nginx.conf, ie. one can write nginx.conf syntax in serve.sh, or does one have to write vagrant config functions that translate to the nginx.conf? Also, does serve.sh do anything else other than configuring nginx.conf?

Comment: I added some more info to my answer: Yes serve.sh creates the server{...} blocks which are included in the nginx.conf http{...} block. This is nginx.conf syntax within the server block.